# Getting a components block text inside the component

Tags: ember.js

If you have a block component **foo-bar** which shows up in the template like this:

```html
{{#foo-bar}}

  <span class='greeting'>Hello</span>
  <span class='person'>{{person}}</span>

{{/foo-bar}}
```

How can the `foo-bar.js` access the block string as html? I figured I could just do something to the effect of:

```js
myBlockContent: Ember.computed(function() {
  return Ember.String.htmlSafe(this.$('div').html());
}
```

This returns a safe string but the `{{person}}` property has not be interpolated into the template.

I created a twiddle that sort of illustrates it (see console.log): [twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com/bd7588ed1689f2869410)

Answer (score 0):

Where does `person` come from? If it is a property of the `foo-bar` template, then you can "pass" it to the `yield`, then pick it up using the "as" syntax when you invoke the template for use inside the block, as in:

```
// foo-bar/template.hbs
{{yield person}}

// foo-bar/component.js
person: Ember.computed('blah', function() { return "Some person"; })

// caller.hbs
{{#foo-bar as |person|}}
  person is {{person}}
  ...
{{/foo-bar}}
```

Comment: My example was simplified for the question but basically where person is less important to me than whether or not I can get back a handlebars interpolated HTML result-set. Does that make sense? In fact, ideally I wouldn't even want to render this into the DOM (but I can do in a hidden fashion if that makes things easier).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this from within the didInsertElement hook. All content will be in the DOM at that point.